# Subversion reported a malfunction 'action == svn_wc_conflict_action_delete' on line 1550 of '..\..\..\subversion\libsvn_wc\update_editor.c

Tags: svn, github, tortoisesvn, git-svn

I have got this error when I'm trying get latest version from GitHub. Do
you have nay experience on this error, please help me!!!

I tried with a complete new checkout and got the same error. Note that its only occurring when I'm checking out from Github. When I checkout from our local SVN repository, it works fine.

```
---------------------------
Subversion Exception!
---------------------------
Subversion encountered a serious problem.
Please take the time to report this on the Subversion mailing list
with as much information as possible about what
you were trying to do.
But please first search the mailing list archives for the error message
to avoid reporting the same problem repeatedly.
You can find the mailing list archives at
http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Subversion reported the following
(you can copy the content of this dialog
to the clipboard using Ctrl-C):

In file
 'D:\Development\SVN\Releases\TortoiseSVN-1.8.6\ext\subversion\subversion\libsvn_wc\update_editor.c'
 line 1550: assertion failed (action == svn_wc_conflict_action_delete)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have tried to find the issue, but unable to find any resolution by Googling.

This issue has been reported here as well by someone else and seems yet not resolved... http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/assert-triggered-in-update-editor-c-td117139.html

Moreover, the issue doesn't seems to be related to TortoiseSVN, because I tried to update repository using AnkhSVN from Visual Studio and I got same error.

```
SharpSvn.SvnMalfunctionException: Subversion reported a malfunction 'action == svn_wc_conflict_action_delete' on line 1550 of '..\..\..\subversion\libsvn_wc\update_editor.c'.
   at ?A0x12823cd1.sharpsvn_malfunction_handler(Int32 can_return, SByte* file, Int32 line, SByte* expr)
   at svn_client_update4(apr_array_header_t** , apr_array_header_t* , svn_opt_revision_t* , svn_depth_t , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , svn_client_ctx_t* , apr_pool_t* )
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Update(ICollection`1 paths, SvnUpdateArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Update(String path, SvnUpdateArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result)
   at Ankh.Commands.SolutionUpdateCommand.PerformUpdate(CommandEventArgs e, ProgressWorkerArgs wa, SvnRevision rev, Boolean allowUnversionedObstructions, Boolean updateExternals, Boolean setDepthInfinity, IEnumerable`1 groups, SvnUpdateResult& updateResult)
   at Ankh.Commands.SolutionUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass9.<OnExecute>b__6(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs a)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

I tried with updating local copy using command prompt svn update.. and got same error..

```
Updating '.':
svn: E235000: In file 'D:\Development\SVN\Releases\TortoiseSVN-1.8.6\ext\subvers
ion\subversion\libsvn_wc\update_editor.c' line 1550: assertion failed (action ==
 svn_wc_conflict_action_delete)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Why would you choose to use graphical-SVNs to checkout from github? Try **git** or the **github** Windows GUI: [https://windows.github.com/](https://windows.github.com/)

Comment: We are more comfortable with SVN and we tried with Git, learned it thoroughly and used it but apart from its faster speed we don't think its better than SVN. Moreover, it has lot of issues when using with Visual Studio, or may be windows.

Comment: Hi, Can you please instead help us point in right direction towards fixing the problem we are facing?

Comment: You gave reasons why you are using SVN.  You have not given good reasons why you are using SVN **with github**.  This is like trying to put a Ford engine in a Chevy.  It can be done, but it introduces all kinds of unnecessary difficulty.  

Try it with a dedicated SVN host and see if your problem persists.  If dedicated SVN client software and a dedicated SVN-native server still have errors on your platform of choice, then it is time for you to reconsider SVN.  Otherwise you can attribute the error to an incompatibility with github's SVN-abstraction.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The repository is hosted at GitHub and thats why we need to use it! Any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: No, I don't know how to fix this and neither does the subversion team:
http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4442

Please understand that github does not actually host SVN repositories: it hosts (as the name suggests) git repositories, and provides a SVN abstraction layer.  Basically it attempts to translate SVN operations to git operations using proprietary code.  This is why nobody but github will know how to fix it or why it occurred.  At best you can try the approach described here: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=39847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue is reported to Github Support and they suggested us to use a standard SVN client, and specifically http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download. Trying to checkout the same repository using same works fine.

If you are facing similar issue, try again with the SilkSVN or some other SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on TortoiseSVN client.
To solve:
install slikSVN
svn cleanup 
svn update